# How can I display an alert with the position of the element that was clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this example:

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/rtcydtyh/2/)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<ul>

    <li id="#bar">
        <img src="http://theimageconference.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/images-50x50.png"width=50 height=50></img>
        <p>ELEMENT 1</p>
    </li>
    <li id="#bar">
        <img src="http://whyfiles.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/promega_logo.png" width=50 height=50></img>
        <p>ELEMENT 2</p>
    </li>
    <li id="#bar">
        <img src="http://bikechicago.com/wp-content/uploads/bikechicago-uber-image-C2.png" width=50 height=50></img>
        <p>ELEMENT 3</p>
    </li>
    <li id="#bar">
        <img src="http://coordinate.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/CBR_Web_Images.jpg" width=50 height=50></img>
        <p>ELEMENT 4</p>
    </li>
    <li id="#bar">
        <img src="http://www.bpifrance-lelab.fr/var/bpi/storage/images/media/images/image-couverture/34625-1-fre-FR/image-couverture_large.jpg" width=50 height=50></img>
        <p>ELEMENT 5</p>
    </li>
    <li id="#bar">
        <img src="http://odpiralnicasi.com/photos/012/539/image-big.jpg" width=50 height=50></img>
        <p>ELEMENT 6</p>
    </li>

</ul>

<div class="dreapta">

</div>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    width:95px;
    float:left;
}

ul li{border-bottom:1px solid;}

p{padding;0;margin:0;}

.dreapta{float:right;width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid;}
```

**CODE JS:**

```
$("ul li").click( function(event)
{
    var barIndex = $( "ul li" ).index();
    alert("Element poistion:"barIndex);

});
```

Basically I want to display an alert position dln element list that you click.

Can you tell me please how to solve this problem and why my code does not work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hope you have posted the correct js code w/o any typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("ul li").click(function (event) {
    var barIndex = $("ul li").index($(this)) + 1;
    alert("Element poistion:" + barIndex);
});
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    width:95px;
    float:left;
}
ul li {
    border-bottom:1px solid;
}
p {
    padding;
    0;
    margin:0;
}
.dreapta {
    float:right;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li id="#bar">
        <img src="http://theimageconference.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/images-50x50.png" width=50 height=50></img>
        <p>ELEMENT 1</p>
    </li>
    <li id="#bar">
        <img src="http://whyfiles.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/promega_logo.png" width=50 height=50></img>
        <p>ELEMENT 2</p>
    </li>
    <li id="#bar">
        <img src="http://bikechicago.com/wp-content/uploads/bikechicago-uber-image-C2.png" width=50 height=50></img>
        <p>ELEMENT 3</p>
    </li>
    <li id="#bar">
        <img src="http://coordinate.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/CBR_Web_Images.jpg" width=50 height=50></img>
        <p>ELEMENT 4</p>
    </li>
    <li id="#bar">
        <img src="http://www.bpifrance-lelab.fr/var/bpi/storage/images/media/images/image-couverture/34625-1-fre-FR/image-couverture_large.jpg" width=50 height=50></img>
        <p>ELEMENT 5</p>
    </li>
    <li id="#bar">
        <img src="http://odpiralnicasi.com/photos/012/539/image-big.jpg" width=50 height=50></img>
        <p>ELEMENT 6</p>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="dreapta"></div>
```